# How to set value in textInput in react native

Tags: react-native

I have one text input in which i'm gonna typing some name while user typing the name get translated and back to set in text Input field how can i do this

```
 <TextInput 
      style={{color:'black',width:width-60, borderColor: 'black'}}
      underlineColorAndroid='black'
      placeholderTextColor="black"
      onChangeText={ (textValue) => this.setState({
        input: textValue}) }
      />
// TRANSLATED TEXT
      <PowerTranslator
      text={this.state.input} />
```

Answer (score 0):

TextInput have prop named "value". 
For setting data to text input, you should set **"value"** to state value.

```
<TextInput
  value={this.props.input} 
/>
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#value

In your code, power translator view component **only for displaying** text.
If you look at this component page, you should use it as service for getting translated text.

```
Translation.get('Engineering physics or engineering science').then(translated => {
//Do something with the translated text  });
```

Comment: How can use { Translation.get('Engineering physics or engineering science').then(translated => {
//Do something with the translated text  }); } as a service and one more thing i just simply want my input get translated and set again overe there on text inpuy

Comment: After using value for TextInput <TextInput  value={this.state.input} /> , set inputvalue's state to translated value like this:  this.setState({input:translated})